# Confused about linked list deletion

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the deletion function in

```
public static boolean delete(Object d, ListElement head){
ListElement p=find(d,head);
if(p.data==null){return false;}
else {
    System.out.println("Delete Successfully!");
    if(head.data==d){head=head.next;}
    else{
    while(head.next.data!=d){
        head=head.next;
    }
    head.next=head.next.next;}
    return true;}

}
```

This function basically check if the element `d` is in the list, 
-if `not->return false;`

-else check whether the element is the first element of the list, if `true`, change the head to its `next`,

-else traverse to the list element in front of it.

The problem is case the element to delete is the first element, such as boolean `s=ListElement.delete(1,d);` I cannot use "`head=head.next;`" to assign new value to head. **But java is passed by reference, why cannot I change that?**

//actually I found my question is whether we can change the reference passed to the function  inside the function
like:

```
    void fun(dog a){
    a=new dog("Po");
}
main()   
{dog b=new dog("Jo");fun(b);}
```

//so will b be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to the first list element is either held by the list object itself or by an "invisible" root element (in case of single linked list).

So you either have to pass the entire list to the method or, if you have that invisible root, pass the root as head.

```
public static boolean delete(Object d, MyLinkedList<ListElement> list) {

  ListElement head = list.getHead();
  if (head.data.equals(d)) {   // <- ALWAYS use equals, never == to compare objects!!
    list.setHead(head.next);
  } else {
    ListElement element = head.next;

    // ... the rest is similiar to your algorithm

  } 
}
```

Comment: this is a solution. Hmm, I tried to avoid using collections to implement my own class. Basically, my question is whether we can change the reference value passed to the function inside a function.

Comment: We can't change "pass by reference", this is fundamental. And, my solution doesn't require to use a Collections class. I'll change the typename to make it clearer :)

Comment: Thx! so I need to add setHead() function inside the MyLinedList class to reset the head. Just wondering if there would be a prettier way to combine two cases( first element or not) together. Really appreciate your responseXD

Answer (score 0):

The Java Pass by Reference idea means, that when you call a method, and give some object as an argument, you'll get a *new* reference pointing to the same object.

Altering values, will change the object, in turn also affecting other references. But if you give a new value to the parameter, only that will be changed, to point to some different object. (It's worth mentioning that there are languages that do allow changing the argument, to change the first passed parameter.)

Answer (score -1):

```
void delete(visit_ptr_node_type this_is_the_node)
{
  visit_ptr_node_type one_back;
  if(anchor == NULL)
    printf("\n The list is empty");
  else
    {
    if(this_is_the_node==anchor)
      anchor=anchor->next_ptr;
    else
      {
      one_back=anchor;
      while(one_back->next_ptr != this_is_the_node)
    one_back=one_back->next_ptr;
      one_back->next_ptr = (this_is_the_node) ->next_ptr;
      }
    free(this_is_the_node);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is (1) not java and (2) uses some global vars (anchor) so the answer doesn't really help solving the underlying "pass by reference in java" problem.